# Error 'on clause' en una query de Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Estaba intentando realizar esta query en MySql pero me salta un error

> "Unknown column 'p.id' in 'on clause'.

Este es el query:

```
SELECT
    d.nombre,
    a.nombre,
FROM
    departamento d 
INNER JOIN
    profesor p ON d.id = p.id_departamento
INNER JOIN
    asignatura a ON p.id = a.id_profesor
LEFT JOIN
    curso_escolar c ON a.curso = c.id
WHERE c.id is NULL;
```

¿En qué me estoy equivocando?

Comment: Sin saber la estructura de las tablas es bastante complicado poder ayudarte, nos falta inforamcion....

Comment: Sin ver la estructura de tus tablas es dificil ayudarte, pero viendo tu query, sospecho que tu error esta en 'ON p.id = a.id_profesor LEFT JOIN', que deberia ser 'ON p.id_profesor = a.id_profesor LEFT JOIN', esto asumiendo que el campo id en tu tabla profesor se llama id_profesor.

Comment: Saludos. Revisa tu estructura de tablas; el error esta en el `p.id = a.id_profesor` el **`p.id`** (campo `id` de la tabla **profesor** no existe). Verifica estes usando los nombres correctos de la tabla.